# How to retrieve a list of subentities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.siteadmin.domain.HostSite.sectionList, no session or session was closed

**Host Site**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hs")
public class HostSite {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="hostSite")
    private List<HostSiteSection> sectionList;
```

**Host Site Section**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hsst")
public class HostSiteSection {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="hsid")
    private HostSite hostSite;
```

**Controller**

```
screenObject.setSectionList(hostSite.getSectionList());
```

**JSP**

```
<c:if test="${screenObject!=null && screenObject.getSectionList()!=null}">
    <c:forEach items="${screenObject.getSectionList()}" var="section">
        <tr>
             <td><a href="../hostSiteSection/${section.id}" target="_blank">${section.id}</a></td>
             <td><a href="../hostSiteSection/${section.id}" target="_blank">${section.name}</a></td>        
             <td>${section.order}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Where is it falling apart? In the controller or jsp? What's the cause? I have tried both eager and lazy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to eagerly load the collection `sectionList` inside the `HostSite`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hs")
public class HostSite {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="hostSite",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<HostSiteSection> sectionList;
```

HQL API docs [reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your hibernate session has closed at the time your code is trying to retrieve the list.  It can also happen if your entity is no longer attached to the session because it closed and reopened.

Just mapping the list as eager might fix this but it's not the best solution.  Using eager fetching heavily can lead to major performance issues with hibernate.

A better solution is to make sure the hibernate session is open and your entity attached to it at the time you use it.  This is probably most easily handled in your situation by attaching a servlet filter for the [open-session-in-view](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) pattern.  Other possible approaches to handling the problem are also described in the hibernate documentation section on [performance fetching initialization](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization).